# Why is captured azure eventhub information for SystemProperties and Properites empty?

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am using Azure EventHub and capturing the contents to blob storage using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-capture-overview.

Now for the generated Avro files, why is the information stored in the `properties` and `System properties` fields empty?

> NOTE Azure is populating these fields

I publish the data using a POST request with my payload as the body and authorization headers set.
Am I missing additional headers which would be required to make Azure fill these columns?

## edit

so the event hub client`s POST method looks like this:

```
    private val SB_URL = "https://$namespace.servicebus.windows.net/$eventHub"
    private val HEADER_AUTHORIZATION = AzureUtil.getSasToken(SB_URL, sas_key_name, sas_key)
    private val HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE = "application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8"

    private val REQ_URL = "https://$namespace.servicebus.windows.net/$eventHub/messages"
    private val REQ_TIMEOUT = "60"
    private val REQ_API_VERSION = "2014-01"

    private val client = OkHttpClient()
    private val JSON = "application/json; charset=utf-8".toMediaType()


    private var callback: Callback? = null

    fun registerCallback(cb: Callback) {
        callback = cb
    }

    fun send(message: String) {
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("$REQ_URL?timeout=$REQ_TIMEOUT&api-version=$REQ_API_VERSION")
            .addHeader("Content-Type", HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE)
            .addHeader("Authorization", HEADER_AUTHORIZATION)
            .post(message.toRequestBody(JSON))
            .build()

        val call = client.newCall(request)

        try {
            val response = call.execute()
            callback!!.onResponse(call, response)
        } catch (error: IOException) {
            callback!!.onFailure(call, error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you add how do you use the post request?

Comment: I added it as requested.